# Only change display if button clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the display of a div that sits inside a form after the invokes a click event on a button. However, the div is defaulting to display none on page load. How can I make div change display only if click event happens on the button?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const userData = {};

function getUserData() {
  let formContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container')[0];
  formContainer.classList.add('hide');
  console.log('inside getUserData');
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let feet = document.getElementById('feet').value;
  let inches = document.getElementById('inches').value;
  let diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;
  console.log(name + ' ' + feet);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', getUserData());
```

```html
<form id="dino-compare">
  <div class="form-container">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input id="name" class="form-field__full" type="name" name="name">
    <p>Height</p>
    <label>Feet: <input id="feet" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="feet"></label>
    <label>inches: <input id="inches" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="inches"></label>
    <p>Weight:</p>
    <label><input id="weight" class="form-field__full" type="number" name="weight">lbs</label>
    <p>Diet:</p>
    <select id="diet" class="form-field__full" name="diet">
      <option>Herbavor</option>
      <option>Omnivor</option>
      <option>Carnivor</option>
    </select>
    <div id="btn" onclick="getUserData()">Compare Me!</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of calling `getUserData`, only pass a reference to `.addEventListener()` function. `btn.addEventListener('click', getUserData());` ----> `btn.addEventListener('click', getUserData);`

Comment: Why you have two event Listener ? One is inline `onclick` and other one `addEventListener` for same `btn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the function in the html attribute `onclick` just use javascript one and assign on it your defined function like the following

### Example

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const userData = {};

function getUserData() {
  let formContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container')[0];
  formContainer.classList.add('hide');
  console.log('inside getUserData');
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let feet = document.getElementById('feet').value;
  let inches = document.getElementById('inches').value;
  let diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;
  console.log(name + ' ' + feet);
}
btn.onclick = () => getUserData();
```

```html
<form id="dino-compare">
  <div class="form-container">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input id="name" class="form-field__full" type="name" name="name">
    <p>Height</p>
    <label>Feet: <input id="feet" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="feet"></label>
    <label>inches: <input id="inches" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="inches"></label>
    <p>Weight:</p>
    <label><input id="weight" class="form-field__full" type="number" name="weight">lbs</label>
    <p>Diet:</p>
    <select id="diet" class="form-field__full" name="diet">
      <option>Herbavor</option>
      <option>Omnivor</option>
      <option>Carnivor</option>
    </select>
    <div id="btn">Compare Me!</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Gad. Why does btn.onclick = () => getUserData(); work and not btn.addEventListener('click', getUserData()); ?

Comment: this works to `btn.addEventListener('click',() => getUserData());`